# missing ';' before 'type'

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student {
    int  rollNo;
    char studentName[25];
    struct student *next;
}node;

node *createList();
void printList(node *);


int main()
{
    node *head;
    head = createList();
    void printList(node *head);



    return 0;
}

node *createList()
{
    int idx,n;
    node *p,*head;
    printf("How many nodes do you want initially?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n); 

    for(idx=0;idx<n;++idx)
    {
        if(idx == 0)
        {
            head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            p = head;
        }
        else
        {
            p->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            p = p->next;
        }
        printf("Enter the data to be stuffed inside the list <Roll No,Name>\n");
        scanf("%d %s",&p->rollNo,p->studentName);

    }
    p->next = NULL;
    p = head;
    /*while(p)
    {
            printf("%d %s-->\n",p->rollNo,p->studentName);
            p=p->next;
    }*/

    return(head);

}

void printList(node *head)
{
    node *p;
    p = head;
    while(p)
    {
        printf("%d %s-->\n",p->rollNo,p->studentName);
        p=p->next;
    }
}
```

What could possibly be wrong here? I know i have done something silly, just can't figure out what it is.
I am getting these errors

```
 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
 error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
  error C2371: 'createList' : redefinition; different basic types
```

Comment: What line does the error message refer to?

Comment: error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'>>>void printList(node *head);
error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*   &  error C2371: 'createList' : redefinition; different basic types  >>> node *createList()

Answer (score 7):

```
int main()
{
    node *head;
    head = createList();
    void printList(node *head); // This isn't how you call a function
    return 0;
}
```

Change to:

```
int main()
{
    node *head;
    head = createList();
    printList(head); // This is.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a programmer mistake, but it shouldn't cause a compiler error.

Comment: `void printList(node *head);` shouldnt this be treated as a declaration?? Why should it cause any problem at all?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Compiling as C with VS2008 gives this error - Compiling as C++ doesn't.

Comment: @Oli It's a compile error in C because declarations have to come before anything else in a function body.

Comment: @David: Ah, yes.  (I should have enabled `-pedantic` in GCC...)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you for your (correct) answer here in the comments. I'm much obliged.

Answer (score 2):

This line in `main()` is your problem:

```
void printList(node *head);
```

It should be:

```
printList(head);
```

You want to be calling the function there, not trying to declare it.