# Syntax error : missing ';' before 'type' C code

Tags: c, compiler-construction, error-handling

Yes, it has been asked before and i have followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693821/missing-before-type) and put my declerations at the top still not working.

```
void map_delete(map_t *map, char *key) {
   assert(map_contains(map, key));

   map_elem_t *prev;
   map_elem_t *elem_to_remove;

   prev = map->elem;
   while(strcmp(prev->next->key, key) != 0) prev= prev->next;

   elem_to_remove = prev->next;
   prev->next = elem_to_remove->next;
   free(elem_to_remove);
}


map.c(74): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
map.c(76): error C2065: 'prev' : undeclared identifier
map.c(76): warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'map_elem_t *'
map.c(77): error C2065: 'prev' : undeclared identifier
map.c(77): error C2223: left of '->next' must point to struct/union
map.c(77): error C2198: 'strcmp' : too few arguments for call
map.c(77): error C2065: 'prev' : undeclared identifier
map.c(77): error C2065: 'prev' : undeclared identifier
map.c(77): error C2223: left of '->next' must point to struct/union
map.c(79): error C2065: 'elem_to_remove' : undeclared identifier
map.c(79): error C2065: 'prev' : undeclared identifier
map.c(79): error C2223: left of '->next' must point to struct/union
map.c(80): error C2065: 'prev' : undeclared identifier
map.c(80): error C2223: left of '->next' must point to struct/union
map.c(80): error C2065: 'elem_to_remove' : undeclared identifier
map.c(80): error C2223: left of '->next' must point to struct/union
map.c(81): error C2065: 'elem_to_remove' : undeclared identifier
map.c(81): warning C4022: 'free' : pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
```

note the logic of the code is correct as it was working on another machine, its the compiler that is not happy with the layout

Comment: `assert(map_contains(map, key));` is not a declaration. (Getting a compiler that supports a more reasonable C standard wouldn't be a bad idea.)

Comment: thanks i wish i could too, tell that to my boss! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler complains because `assert` is not a declaration. You'll need to move the `assert` so that it comes after the declarations.

Using a C compiler that supported a standard more recent that C89 would be a good move.